# How to add JAX-RS Response in OpenAPI YAML file

Tags: rest, jax-rs, httpresponse, openapi

I have a REST service and I have defined the API signature using OpenAPI's YAML file.

Something like,

```
title: Sample Pet Store App
description: This is a sample server for a pet store.
termsOfService: http://example.com/terms/
contact:
  name: API Support
  url: http://www.example.com/support
  email: support@example.com
paths:
  v1/employees/{employeeId}:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            ....
```

From the YAML file, I generate the API requests using something like [OpenAPI generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

But how do I specify a https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html, in my YAML file?

This is how I want to send a response from my Java code. I want to know how I can add [this Response object](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) to OpenAPI's YAML?

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/v1/employees")
public Response getEmployee(String employeeId) {
 
    // ...
 
    return Response
      .status(Response.Status.OK)
      .entity(employee)
      .build();
}
```

I am new to REST API development. I [checked the documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/), but couldn't find details in OpenAPI's on how to add a Javax Response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, instead of returning a Response object, I went with throwing a javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException and adding an ExceptionTranslator code to convert all my exceptions into a WebApplicationException.

Here is a sample code on the exception translation.

```
// Actual code to convert Java exception into javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(getResponse(e));
}

// Exception translation code sample. This can be made into a nice generic function to handle different types of exceptions.
Response getResponse(Throwable t) {
    if (throwable instanceof NotFoundException) {
        Error error = new Error();
            error.setType("404");
            error.setMessage("Requested entry could not be found");

        Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
            .entity(error)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the template you use, by default it is not there, but you can create a custom template to use.

[here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator#template-creator) is the list of available templates.

you must specify type of response you return on OpenAPI spec. like this:

```
v1/employees/{employeeId}:
get:
  operationId: getUser
  responses:
    200:
      description: Return user
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/UsertResponseDTO'
```

after that, if you use default template, add manually typo response like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/v1/employees")
public Response getEmployee(String employeeId) {
 
    // ...
 
    return Response.ok(employee).build();
}
```